# Why is there a polymorphic relationship?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, polymorphism, associations

why is there a polymorphic relationship? Why is this polymorphic relationship used if the database tables are not normalized? Is this something designed to keep less data in the database? I am researching 2 days, but I have not found a consistent answer. Can you help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A polymorpic relationship is used when a relationship can apply to multiple models at the same time.

Let's say you have a model called `Profile` that holds all administrative data for `Teacher` and `Student`

with relationships like :

```
Student has_one :profile
Teacher has_one :profile
Profile belongs_to :student
Profile belongs_to :teacher
```

Now lets say you pick the first record of `Profile` :

```
@p = Profile.first
```

And you want to get the parent of this record .. Well this is a problem because you don't know if you have to do `@p.student` or `@p.teacher`

Then the polymorphic association can prove useful, it adds two fields to `Profile`: the class of the parent and the id of the parent. And it solves the problem of knowing what parent it applies to.

You just have to call an intermediary abtstract model (let's say `Profileable` that doesnt really exists in the database as a table but leads to the parent whithout knowing its class)